# Match Multiple IP Adresses per line

Tags: c#, regex

I try to match a string with a regex having the rule that they all start with `10.20`

```
string str = @"10.20.30.1\r\n10.20.40.2\r\n10.20.50.3";
string pattern = @"(10\.20.+(\r\n)*)+";

var m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str, pattern);
```

However it only catches first line, i.e.:

```
Console.Write(m.ToString()); // prints 10.20.30.1,
```

EDIT: I try to differentiate the case where there is single or multiple lines. i.e. in the above example of `str`, if the user gives

```
string pattern = @"(10\.20.+)+";
```

it matches only first line, which I expect.
what am I missing?

Comment: Your code, for me, is correct: m.toString() = `"10.20.30.1\r\n10.20.40.2\r\n10.20.50.3"`. Run the code you just posted again.

Comment: "if the user gives..."  Is the user giving the IP addresses, or the pattern?

Comment: As I said in my answer, the problem is: `.` matches any single character except \n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `Matches` instead of `Match`. You're looking for multiple matches:

```
var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(
    "10.20.30.1\r\n10.20.40.2\r\n10.20.50.3",
    @"(10\.20.+(\r\n)*)+",
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

Assert.AreEqual(3, matches.Count);
```

In reply to the comment below, to get all the matches as a `string`:

```
var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(
        "foo 10.20.30.1\r\n10.20.40.2\r\n10.20.50.3 bar",
        @"(10\.20\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(\r\n)*)+",
        RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant)
    .ToString();
```

It's best to use a `Regex` that is as specific as possible, but still matches all your criteria. Since `.` matches everything except `\n`, there's still a solution to come up with something like `@"(10\.20\.([^\r])+(\r\n)*)+"`. Though this will match `10.20.30.1\r\n10.20.40.2\r\n10.20.50.3 bar` if you still have other information around it.

Comment: I am trying to get the whole string not the single lines

Answer (score 1):

You defined your string as a verbatim string (with `@` character):

```
string str = @"10.20.30.1\r\n10.20.40.2\r\n10.20.50.3";
```

so `\` will not work as the escape character. Remove the `@` from the beginning of the string definition.

The problem with your pattern is that `.+` in `@"(10\.20.+(\r\n)*)+"` will consume the `\r`, and the remaining string starts with `\n` which deos not match `(\r\n)*`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) says that dot (`.`):

> Matches any single character except \n.

To avoid that, try to use a more accurate pattern to match numbers in parts of the IP address, as **Caramiriel** states in his answer.

You can also change the pattern to:

```
string pattern = @"(10\.20.+(\r\n?|\n)*)+";
```

which is more accurate to match new-line character.

Comment: I think you are forgetting, though, that the regex engine will backtrack when the `\n` fails to match. The fact that `.+` is used isn't the problem; it's the literal escaping of `\r\n` by way of `@` that you mentioned.

Comment: @KennethK. I guess not. Try the regex withoud `@`, and you see that it only matches the first IP. I tried other combinations with simple strings, and this was what I came to. Try `Regex.Match("tall\r\ntill", "(t.+(\r\n)*)+")`, and the length of the match is 5 (`tall\r`).

Comment: @MD.Unicorn, Kenneth is talking about the **target** string (`str` in your example).  The *regex* string can go either way: `"\n"` gets converted by the C# compiler to a linefeed, which matches a literal linefeed;  `@"\n"` remains the two-character sequence `\n`, which the *regex* compiler recognizes as the escape sequence for a linefeed.